# Scrollable contextual voice commands - Google Glass

Tags: android, google-glass

I'm using Google Glass' contextual voice commands and I'm having a problem where not all of the items I'm including are showing up.

For example:

I have a bunch of Universities

- University 1
- University 2
- University 3
- University 4
- University 5
- University 6
- University 7
- etc.....

Every list item below University 6 is cut off and does not show. Is there anyway that I could implement a scroll feature like the picture I posted below?

[Scrollable contextual voice command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Z54.png)